# Calling Authenticated Beebole API using Python

Tags: python, api

So I need to call beebole APIs with python. (documentation https://beebole.com/timesheet-api/).

I would also like to save the call in a csv/excel file (but for now If I am able to make the request work, is already a big step)

I am trying the following - with the service person.get without success (I only get the message - process finished with code 0)

```
import requests
payload = {
    "service": "person.get",
    "id": user_ID
}
auth = {
    "username": "token",
    "password": "password"
}

url = "https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2"

req = requests.get(url, params=payload, auth=auth).json()

print(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't already solve it. This should work for you:

```
import requests
payload = {
    "service": "person.get",
    "id": user_ID
}
auth = ("token", 'x')

url = "https://beebole-apps.com/api/v2"

req = requests.post(url, json=payload, auth=auth).json()

print(req)
```